# How to trace the communication and the relation between microservices without using platforms like jaeger or zipkin?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices

I want to make a diagram of microservices. I'm trying to trace which ones are connected just by reading the code. When I tried to search the names of the other microservices I found nothing. Where should I look? Which path should I follow? Microservices are using RabbitMQ to communicate.I hope I have clearly explained my problem.

I have tried to look into controller or service layer but I lost in the code.